# How to substitue a pattern with a whole array using sed?

Tags: arrays, regex, linux, bash, set

I have an array, which looks like this:

```
snakes=(python boa cornsnake milksnake)
```

I was wondering if it's possible to substitute a pattern with a whole array using sed.
I was thinking about something like this:

```
sed -i "s/snakes like/& $(echo ${snakes[@]})/g" snakes.txt
```

And have the output here like this separated by `,` :

```
snakes like python, boa, cornsnake, milksnake
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: why can't you do `sed -i "s/snakes like/python, boa, cornsnake, milksnake/g" snakes.txt`?

Comment: i use this array in other places and don't want to create additional variable or long sed command. That's why i asked a question, if it's possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that by just expanding the array correctly.

Suppose you want to edit a file called languages (snakes are gross):

```
$ cat languages
I like languages like.
```

And your array is like this:

```
$ langs=(python perl ruby lua)
```

You just have to

- set `IFS=,` (Internal Field Separator)
- convert all the elements of your array to a single string with `${langs[*]}`
- prepend a space before each one of them by replacing the beginning of each
  string (`#` in bash, like `^` in regex) with a space

The final command is simply this one:

```
$ IFS=, ; sed -i "s|languages like|&${langs[*]/#/ }|" languages
```

(I used `|` in the sed command for clarity, but `/` would be fine too, since
your shell is converting `${langs[*]/#/ }` to the final string before passing
it to sed)

The languages file now looks like this:

```
I like languages like python, perl, ruby, lua.
```

Comment: @BallPython I added a small explanation.

Answer (score 1):

With this definition for the array:

```
$ snakes=(python boa cornsnake milksnake)
```

We need two steps.  The first is to create a string `s` which will contain the elements of the array `snakes` separated by a comma and a space:

```
$ printf -v s ', %s' "${snakes[@]}"
```

Then, use `s` in the `sed` command:

```
$ sed -i "s/snakes like/& ${s:2}/g" snakes.txt
```

`${s:2}` is used to eliminate the extra comma-space that occurs at the beginning of `s`.

#### Example

Consider this sample file:

```
$ cat snakes.txt 
I like snakes like.
I don't like snakes.
```

Apply `sed`:

```
$ sed -i "s/snakes like/& ${s:2}/g" snakes.txt
```

The file now contains:

```
$ cat snakes.txt 
I like snakes like python, boa, cornsnake, milksnake.
I don't like snakes.
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion +1. I think i found out how to make oneliner.